# Jhipster React Form Grid Layout Issue

Tags: forms, gridview, jhipster, reactstrap

I'm currently using the latest version of Jhipster 7.6.0 and Node 16.14.0. If we try to arrange form fields in column view in other words if we wrap ValidatedField to  and , the field values are not populated during Edit mode of the page and the same is true for insert mode. The attached link is showing a simple layout change on the existing user management page, and we are trying to see Last Name and First Name in one row, and we are unable to see the value or update the value if we realign these fields in multiple columns views.

Does anyone know a simple workaround we can use ValidatedForm and ValidatedField in Row, Col, and regular CRUD works like with other pages generated by the framework? Please let me know if more clarification or detail is needed on this case.

[Layout and code Sample from User Management page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfJ2R.png)

Comment: Thanks to Emilpaw from Jhipster community, The reason it is not working because ValidatedField should be direct child of ValidatedForm. If anyone looking for the nested structure sample code, here is the sample code written by Emilpaw  https://github.com/emilpaw/jhipster-react-nested-form-inputs-example/commit/78edc394869673b8d31d182496d6a3adcfbfd35a#

Comment: Does not help but here  is what I found : ValidatedField has to parameters : row (boolean) and col (any). 
when row is true, then it creates the element row. But I did not find how to put more than one field....